# SQL Statement for counting how many times a record is changed

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a unique requirement where I have 3 audit tables where any time a change is made it creates a new record for the change.  now I need to create a view that will get the distinct order id's and how many time they are changed in the 3 respected tables.

this is my SQL I have developed

```
select  distinct orderid as salesorderid,COUNT (*) AS SALESORDERUPDATE  
FROM  foobar 
where ModifiedDateTime>'2015-11-01 20:44:55.107' group by Orderid
union all 
select  distinct orderid as salesorderid,count(*)  SALESORDERUPDATE  AS   
from foobar1 
where ModifiedDateTime>'2015-11-01 20:44:55.107' group by OrderID
union all
select distinct orderid as salesorderid,count(*)AS SALESORDERUPDATE  
from foobar2 
where ModifiedDateTime>'2015-11-01 20:44:55.107' group by  Orderid;
```

Now the results I get  are like this 
for orderid  1 i have 3 entries showing different values for count (*).  I want to sum that up in one line

so it would be something like

```
orderid  123  salesorderupdate(20) 
as suppose to 
orderId 123 salesorderupdate(10)
orderid 123 salesorderupdate(7)
orderid 123 salesorderupdate(3)
```

Thanks,

Comment: just put this at the beginning..  `SELECT orderid, SUM(SALESORDERUPDATE) FROM (`  and this at the end `) t GROUP BY t.orderid`

Comment: you don't need the distinct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
 select orderID, sum(salesorderupdate)
 from 
 (the query from your question goes here) temp
 group by orderId
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your query the subtable, then select the id and the sum

```
select distinct orderid, sum(SALESORDERUPDATE)
from (
select  distinct orderid as salesorderid,COUNT (*) AS SALESORDERUPDATE  
FROM  foobar 
where ModifiedDateTime>'2015-11-01 20:44:55.107' group by Orderid
union all 
select  distinct orderid as salesorderid,count(*)  SALESORDERUPDATE  AS   
from foobar1 
where ModifiedDateTime>'2015-11-01 20:44:55.107' group by OrderID
union all
select distinct orderid as salesorderid,count(*)AS SALESORDERUPDATE  
from foobar2 
where ModifiedDateTime>'2015-11-01 20:44:55.107' group by  Orderid;
) changes group by orderid;
```

Comment: The word `distinct` is not necessary here.  The `group by` clause takes care of that.

Comment: Good point. I saw he was doing it in his original query and thought it might sql-server thing.